# is the iOs simulator buggy when it comes to orientation detection?

Tags: javascript, ipad, orientation

I am testing a piece of code on the ios simulator you get from apple (xcode).
basically I am trying to reset the scaling when the user rotates the ipad but on the simulator it is so inconsistant. I originally had the basic code to say if orientation is 90 do this, if it is -90 do that and so on but if my original orientation is landscape or portrait it might screw up. is this behavior just with ios simulator or the same as ipad, i don't have an ipad with me so i cannot verify

when i reset the scaling i am first removing the meta tag content all together then adding to content again because if i dont do so, it does not work at all

sample code would be, i have tried using device width, it just screws up. I dont want to use css because the content is fix width so i just need to rescale. is my method wrong? is there another tested approach? I used a switch statement before but i find the if much simpler. thank you

```
if (orientation == 0 || orientation == 180) {
        viewport.attr("content", "");
        viewport.attr("content", "user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, width=990px");
    }
    else {
        viewport.attr("content", "");
        viewport.attr("content", "user-scalable=no, initial-scale=0.77, minimum-scale=0.77, maximum-scale=0.77, width=990px");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes the orientation can be "unknown".

Comment: I have an alert and every time the orientation comes up as the correct number but the behavior is almost random. i checked on an ipad just now and it is the same. is there no way to correctly use JS to alter viewport? I almost feel like the original orientation is always 0 and then it just goes + or - 90 each time you change it. either that or the scaling is buggy

Comment: In my experience in the simulator it always starts off as orientation unknown. I'd just test on device to make sure it works how you want there for these sort of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XCode simulator is pretty good and i never had problems with it besides it sometimes react a bit slow to orientation changes.

If you would want to check it with JavaScript i think you would best try comparing the window.innerHeight to the window.innerWidth and see which one is largest.

I made a test page a while back which uses only CSS to test for certain media query things.
link: http://pm5544.eu/mp/
Notice that when in landscape orientation the device width and height do not change, this was (at least to me) a bit counter-intuitive, so it might be that the iOS devices give unexpected info sometimes.

May i ask why you don't want to use CSS for this because it sounds like it is very doable.

PM5544.

Comment: my content is fixed width and it's a huge project so there is no time to create a completely new css for portrait. i will have to use the innerheight/width method and see if i can get it to work because the orientation way is not working at all

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if the orientation needs to be a degree, `-90, 90`. If it doesn't then you could try using..

`orientation == landscape`

It's a valid CSS3 media query
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/how-to-use-css3-orientation-media-queries/

Comment: i can't change the css i need another approach other than css